# Error rendering VBOs

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

Using the below method to render with vbos, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled
```

Rendering method:

```
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexHandle);
    GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalHandle);
    GL11.glNormalPointer(GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, this.faces.size() * 3);

    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried putting the enables before the array pointer calls? You shouldn't *have* to, but LWJGL seems to prefer that you did.

Comment: What enables do I have to put in?

Comment: `glEnableClientState`: That enable.

Comment: No it still doesn't work

Comment: Nevermind, I found out that I forgot to initialize the VBOs. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the array buffer object, in your case vertexHandle or normalHandle is not linked to any source with data. Try checking your initialization of the array buffer objects.